# Why does Azure describe "Runtime Stack" in App Service Overview as "Dotnetcore - 7.0" on Linux, but as "Dotnet - v7.0" on Windows?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

Not a problem per se, more of a curiosity that no one has the answer to.

We have switched to deploying our .NET APIs to Linux hosts in Microsoft Azure. We develop on Windows desktops and the environment runs on .NET 7 in Windows, and the selection of "Stack" / ".NET version" in either Azure Windows or Linux hosts are the same, i.e. ".NET" / ".NET 7 (STS)".
However in the Overview screen, "Runtime Stack" in App Service Overview screen is displayed as "Dotnetcore - 7.0" on a Linux OS, but as "Dotnet - v7.0" on a Windows OS.

I understood the cross-platform compatibility meant they were the same regardless of host, yet they are described differently. What bothers me is that we were supposed to be moving away from "core", and here it still is. Just a typo on Microsoft's part perhaps, or deliberate as a shortcut to determine the OS?

Comment: The reason for this is just only to differentiate the environment(windows/linux).It does not effect any of the performance.

Comment: For me It is showing `Dotnetcore` for [Windows](https://i.imgur.com/apsCY6t.png) and `Dotnetcore - 7.0` for [Linux](https://i.imgur.com/EFuGWqf.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to check the same in my Environment with `.NET 7 (STS)`.

For Azure App service deployed in Windows it is displayed as `Dotnetcore`.

[image]

and for Linux App service I can see as `Dotnetcore - 7.0`.

[image]

> What bothers me is that we were supposed to be moving away from "core", and here it still is

- I have changed the Version from `.NET 7(STS)` to `ASP.NET V4.8` in Azure Windows App Service.

[image]

- Now it has been changed to `Dotnet - v4.0`

[image]

- Now again I have changed it to `.NET 7`, now it is shown as `Dotnet - v7.0`.

[image]

AFAIK, it does not affect any of the performance and the change we see is only to differentiate the environment and help the users to differentiate in a better way.

It is displaying as Dotnet even after updating to CORE later.

As we don`t have 7 version in Framework, do not worry about it, the configuration will be taken as CORE itself (even if displayed as Dotnet).

Comment: @Karlossus - Have you observed the same?

Comment: yes, same as per your screenshots. I also noticed for our older Windows app service that was using the now deprecated .NET Core 3.1, the Configuration / General Settings / Stack setting is now blank, and the Overview Runtime Stack displays simply "Dotnetcore".